# Yii: Throws exception on any function call when using Xdebug, works when not debugging

Tags: php, yii, xdebug

During debug, I'm experiencing a problem where any function call within my Controller action method will throw an exception, but when running the code without the debugger, it does not occur. I am using Xdebug 2.2.3, with Yii framework 1.1.14.

My Controller class is called `TesterController`, and this happens in the `actionIndex`:

```
class Controller extends CController
{
    public $layout='//layouts/column1';
    public $menu=array();
    public $breadcrumbs=array();
}

class TesterController extends Controller {

    public function actionIndex() {
        printf("test\n");
        $this->render('index');
    }

}
```

When attempting to step into the printf function, execution goes to the following Yii exception handler:

```
public function handleException($exception)
{
    // disable error capturing to avoid recursive errors
    restore_error_handler();
    restore_exception_handler();
```

...

where `$exception` complains that property `TesterController.email` does not exist. I've tried viewing the stack and exception traces, updating to the latest version of Xdebug, updating to the latest version of Yii, deleting all cache, grepping my code for any references to this property (`email`), and recreating my Controller and View classes from scratch to no avail. I've reduced it to this minimal demonstrable case, and I'm at a loss for what to try next besides rebuilding my Yii installation from scratch. Something tells me it might be related to PHP magic getters. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you post `index` view? Possibly refering to email like that:`$this->email` in your view

Comment: what happens when you comment out the `$this->render('index');` ???

Comment: xdebug should tell file and line of where error occurs.  did you check it? why did you decide that problem is related to controller code?

Comment: My index view isn't referring to email, and the problem still happens with $this->render('index') commented out. This is my index view:
`<?php
/* @var $this TesterController */

$this->breadcrumbs=array(
    'Tester',
);
?>
<h1><?php echo $this->id . '/' . $this->action->id; ?></h1>
`

Comment: All other things being the same, I switched from Netbeans 7.3 to Eclipse PDT 3.2 and the issue has resolved. I don't have time to track it down, so I'm planning to just stick with Eclipse PDT. What's the proper StackOverflow etiquette here? Can the question be retracted?